# How to disable or remove DirectoryListingModule in IIS to prevent HTTP 405 error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I've written an ASP.Net web app with a custom HTTP handler. However, after importing the app into IIS 7.5, IIS returns this when the app is invoked:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
```

When I enable the Failed Request Tracing Rules feature to trap HTTP 405 errors I see this:

[image]

My handler does not get invoked. So I'd like to remove the DirectoryListingModule. But, similar to @Brendan Hill [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21842206/1843329), nothing I've tried seems to disable the module. Even commenting out all the lines that mention this module in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config doesn't work:

```
<!--add name="DirectoryListingModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\dirlist.dll" /-->
<!--add name="DirectoryListingModule" lockItem="true" /-->
<!--add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" /-->
```

Like @Brendan Hill I would prefer a solution in my app's Web.config so I don't have to fiddle with IIS's settings. Excerpt from my current Web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="AuthServiceHandler"
           path="*."
           verb="*"
           type="AuthServiceHTTPHandler.App_Code.AuthServiceHandler"
           preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

If I import my app into the Default Web Site in IIS and bind it to 9000 I can invoke the app with a POST request to http://localhost:9000 . This URL is fine; I'm not trying to request any web pages.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I worked around the problem by creating a dummy web page and binding the handler to that for the POST verb I was interested in:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="AuthServiceHandler"
           path="dummy.html"
           verb="POST"
           type="AuthServiceHTTPHandler.App_Code.AuthServiceHandler"
           preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

The handler would then be triggered for calls to http://localhost:9000/Auth/dummy.html, where Auth was the name of my app when deployed under the Default Web Site in IIS. (I hadn't appreciated I needed the context as well when I posted the question above.) So the DirectoryListingModule was effectively bypassed.

Handily, by binding the handler to the POST verb only you can use the same 'dummy' web page to provide useful info for users if they browse to it in a web browser (because the browser sends a GET request which won't be intercepted by the handler).

No IIS settings needed to be changed. This worked for me using IIS 7.5 on Windows 7.